# Multiplication of only numeric values of a data frame

Tags: r

I have this data frame and I want to multiply all its numeric values by 100. 
If I use `df*100`, I get NA's for all entries in the country column.

What's the best way of multiplying the data frame without having `NA`'s replacing the countries' names?

```
                         country   gdp.stdv con.stdv[, 2] inv.stdv[, 2] gov.stdv[, 2]
1                      Australia 0.01317959   0.010973106    0.03932870   0.016814514
2                        Austria 0.01238430   0.011640438    0.03281213   0.008398618
3                         Canada 0.01357573   0.011042443    0.03991174   0.014100187
4  European Union (15 countries) 0.01073943   0.007744634    0.02606627   0.005658542
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Over 4 years later, with a bit more R under my belt, I take a go at this one:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a = letters[1:10], b = 1:10)

mutate_if(df, is.numeric, ~ . * 100)
```

Answer (score 3):

First, identify the columns that are numeric, then run those columns through `lapply`.

```
numeric_cols <- vapply(df, is.numeric, logical(1))
df[, numeric_cols] <- lapply(df[, numeric_cols, drop = FALSE],
                             function(x) x * 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply` to identify numeric columns, and then multiply those times 100

```
set.seed(321)
dat <- data.frame(country = c("Australia", "Austria", "Canada", "European"), 
              x1 = rnorm(4), 
              x2 = rnorm(4),
              x3 = rnorm(4))
dat
    country         x1         x2         x3
1 Australia  1.7049032 -0.1239606  0.3391139
2   Austria -0.7120386  0.2681838 -0.5519147
3    Canada -0.2779849  0.7268415  0.3477014
4  European -0.1196490  0.2331354  1.4845918

cols <- sapply(dat, is.numeric)
dat[, cols] <- dat[, cols] * 100
dat

    country        x1        x2        x3
1 Australia 170.49032 -12.39606  33.91139
2   Austria -71.20386  26.81838 -55.19147
3    Canada -27.79849  72.68415  34.77014
4  European -11.96490  23.31354 148.45918
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's only in the first column you could do something like:

```
cbind(df[1],(df[-1]*100))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `mutate_each_` function in `dplyr` package to do the same. First define the function

```
times100 <- function(x){x * 100}
```

then,

```
mutate_each_(df, funs(times100), names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric))))
```

which applies the function to all columns evaluated by `names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric)))`